# One-pulley CVT?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I wonder if an automobile CVT could ditch the secondary set of pulleys by having the chain/belt drive the output shaft directly.  Gear ratios would result from movement of the drive-pulley set only.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

CVTs keep the chain-belt tensioned by changing the diameter of both pulleys at the same time. Adding a tensioner to the mix would create complications with respect to the diameter of the variable pulley, but could be managed either mechanically or via software.

Creating a single variable diameter pulley design will reduce the range of effective gearing, however.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I figured there would have to be something like a derailleur to take up slack, but if this setup would also need a huge pulley to keep the same range of ratios, I see it's not worth it, vs any other benefits one pulley might provide.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly. This is in fact the principle of the automatic belt-drive transmission used in millions of Peugeot and Motobecane mopeds: only the front drive pulley affixed to the crankshaft changes diameter in response to load; the rear (driven) pulley has a fixed diameter. To take up the resulting slack, the entire engine swings fore and aft against a torsion spring, with its swing pivot being a long bolt that runs horizontally through the cylinder head (this is called the "frankenstein bolt"), which bolt also attaches the engine to the frame.

The variable drive ratio helps the moped accelerate better at low speeds. Since the moped's top speed is limited to about 32MPH and the engine size (and hence horsepower rating) is limited to 50cc, the "top gear" ratio is chosen to put the peak of the engine's power output curve at 32MPH and the extra ratio multiplication that could be gotten by varying the effective diameter of both pulleys is unnecessary.

Rubber "V-belt" drives work great for engines of a few horsepower but for more than that you need to double up or triple up the number of belts to share the load. This is satisfactory up to about 20HP; beyond that rubber belts are not commonly used.

Comment: CVTs for motor vehicles use a "belt" design that is a series of steel/metal hollow teeth threaded on a flexible belt. The sides of the pulleys engage the sides of the teeth and push them along the flexible belt. The entire assembly is in a lubrication bath to reduce friction (the enemy of the rubber belt version) to keep efficiency as high as possible. Depending on the OPs requirements, there may not be sufficient space to use a pivoting motor mount or similar, or the gear range may be too small.

Comment: @fred_dot_u, yes yes, my ex's subaru outback had one of those, a truly marvelous piece of engineering.